# I put a UIimageview in LaunchImage.xib ,but it keep showing the copyright information

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, launch-screen

I don't know how to use LaunchImage.xib file , I am new here ,because I use the image asset , but recently I need add landscape launch image , but It doesn't work if I use Image Asset , so I have to use the LaunchImage.xib But I never used before , SO I put an Imageview inside and put a image there , but after I launch the app , the launch image keep showing the copyright information and the the name of the app, It is not the image :(

why this and how to handle this problem :( how can I add landscape launch image , I met a big problem .
I use Xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

In your Target's "General" tab make sure that you have your LaunchScreen.xib file selected under "Launch Screen File".  Also when you select your LaunchScreen.xib and then select it's View there's a property under the section called "Interface Builder Document" called "Use as Launch Screen".  Make sure that's selected.

Comment: I did , and I found that it only works on simulator , if i use a real device , it doesn't work , the launch image is still black , i don't know why

Comment: Try cleaning the project files and device first.  I've found xibs aren't always copied to the device again when changed.  A clean should force it to copy your resources again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a launch screen file correctly set in your target information page :

[image]

Comment: yes , I  did , but if I use simulator , It works fine , but if I run it in real device , It doesn't work :(, The launch image is still black

Comment: Sometimes you have to reinstall the app in order to have the .plist file updated, you should try

Comment: But I didn't do anything in .plist

Comment: The information you find in your target information page are just a readable version of your plist. By setting the Launch screen file, in fact you are adding a value with the key `UILaunchStoryboardName` in your .plist file.